# Installation of Apache Tomcat Server Issue on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, installation

I was trying to add Tomcat 7 in my Eclipse on Mac OS X. When I click “Add new server” in Eclipse and select “Tomcat v7.0 Server”, the field “Server Name” is blank and I cannot type in anything in that textbox.

What I did before is I deleted a Tomcat 7 server from Eclipse and I was trying to reinstall Tomcat 7. But it doesn’t allow me to type anything in that textbox and I cannot proceed to the “Next” button.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a problem which is a bug in eclipse. Try following, it should work:

Here is the workaround that worked for me:

1. Close Eclipse.
2. In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings.
   delete the following two files:

   *org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs*

   *org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs*
3. Restart Eclipse